# Existe Alguma documentação/Exemplo do SignalR para Android?

Tags: android, signalr

Estou tentando utilizar o SignalR  para enviar msgs para dispositivos com o SO Android, encontrei uma biblioteca [SignalR Java](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client), porém não consigo encontrar nenhuma documentação seja oficial ou não. Existe alguma documentação da SignalR para Android ? Ou Algum tutorial/exemplo em Android(a se comunicando com um servidor  ?

obs: Estou desenvolvendo utilizando Eclipse/Android studio. (JAVA)